# my url for json does not work

Tags: android, json

every time i try to print json file from my wamp server it doesn't work 
i use this URL "http://127.0.0.1/webapp/users.php" to acsess the json data
but when i put another link like "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/"
it works perfectly , so i don't know what is the problem exactly 
i'm just starting to learn about json parsing in android .
any help?

my php code is

$row['id'],
        'username'=>$row['username'],
        'password'=>$row['password'],
    ));
}

print json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($conn);

?>

Comment: This is all of your code from php file or only fragment? Before using any API request in your android/any app, try every request in any rest client (perhaps 'insomnia' from chrome web store). Check if you get exactly that what you await for.

Comment: did you try inspecting your ip address, look at my solution

Comment: it is because thier api is publicly hosted , and yours is not it is local to your system.make sense>

Comment: Have you ever used ngrok as a tunneling server

Comment: http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/

Answer (score 0):

Of course i wont work, this address is local address for your own work station(computer or any device with a ip address eg, your own phone as that address) that is why it is local ip address. Only your system can read and write to it. To over come this dilemma , either one host your on a server, or go the cheap way and broadcast your ip address to the internet using a tunneling software such as ngrok.

Here are some advantages:

> Don’t constantly redeploy your in-progress work to get feedback from clients. ngrok creates a secure public URL (https://yourapp.ngrok.io) to a local webserver on your machine. Iterate quickly with immediate feedback without interrupting flow.
>
> Test mobile apps against a development backend running on your machine. Point ngrok at your local dev server and then configure your app to use the ngrok URL. It won't change, even when you change networks.
>
> Building webhook integrations can be a pain: it requires a public address and a lot of set up to trigger hooks. Save yourself time and frustration with ngrok. Inspect the HTTP traffic flowing over your tunnel. Then, replay webhook requests with one click to iterate quickly while staying in context.
>
> Host personal cloud services on your own private network. Run webmail, file syncing, and more securely on your hardware with full end-to-end encryption.

ngrok is easy to install. Download a single binary with zero run-time dependencies for any major platform. Unzip it and then run it from the command line.

After reading and deliberation on some links i received at the courtesy @ cricket_007, there is another way to access your local ip address across the network from wamp server.
try [this](http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/), it works its just a bit longer to setup vs ngrok thats very easy, try the option thats work for you.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Ngrok is only useful over an external network. Obtaining the local IP address of the server is more correct

Comment: ngrok makes a local computer , public to the internet thus making it accessible to everyone, i am using as we speak to host my local ip and share it with my colleagues, so what exactly are you saying? it cannot do it or what i am puzzled by the aforementioned.

Comment: The question is running a WAMP server. So, getting `192.168.1.x`, for example, simply using `ipconfig`. Ngrok does not need downloaded to solve the problem of understanding how networking works, it just drills a hole through your whole firewall

Comment: ipconfig wont work, in the end it will still local, you wanna why, becuase all device has that address, so in this android as that local ip address, he needs a way to serve that content on his system, so either he hosts it publicly using a cloud provider or host it ngrok.

Comment: all he wants is to access his api end point on his system thats all really, your statement wont really help,since ipconfig is always local

Comment: No offense, I don't think you understand networking either. ipconfig is a LAN network. `127.0.0.1`, is not in a network. `192.168.1.x`, for example, is (and should be) accessible to any and all devices of the same LAN network... Cloud is completely unnecessary. Public address of ngrok is also unnecessary. Feel free to try for yourself

Comment: I'll just leave this here... http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/

Comment: It seems you misunderstood me, but point taken , ill admit, i never tried that approach, i have gained some insight, thank you!

Comment: I think I understood. Ngrok makes it easy, but I was simply responding to "ipconfig won't work"

Comment: i edited my answer to facilitate the link you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142402/discussion-between-remario-and-cricket-007).